# How to transpose input variables from excel?

Tags: r

I have an excel sheet of about 240 x 9 matrix. I want to transpose it to 9 x 240 matrix in R programming without manipulating the main excel file. Regression modelling

Comment: Load the data, assign to dataframe and then use `t(data)`!

Answer (score 0):

Agreed that you want the `t()` function. below is a basic example to show you how what to expect.

`d1 <- data.frame(1:3)`

`print(d1)` output is below

```
   X1.3
1    1
2    2
3    3
```

Then we do `t(d1)`, which output is below

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
X1.3    1    2    3
```